# Find Subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find subspaces $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for which the union of $A$ and $B$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm not sure how to start this!

Answer (score 1):

Let the subspaces be $\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb R\}$ and $\{(x,-x):x\in\mathbb R\}$ and then verify that they are subspaces whose union is not a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Choose any 2 one-dimensional subspaces which are not equal. Choose a non-zero vector from each subspace in the union and take the sum. Show that if the sum is contained in the union then both of the chosen vectors belong to the same subspace, contradicting that the subspaces are different.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the picture to have in your head. These are all the subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$:

- Exactly one $0$-dimensional subspace, the point $\{(0,0)\}$.
- Many $1$-dimensional subspaces, the lines through the origin. (Tell me if you don't understand why these are the $1$-dimensional subspaces.) That is, each $1$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ is a line in the plane which travels through the point $(0,0)$.
- Exactly one $2$-dimensional subspace, the entire plane $\mathbb R^2$.

Now the intersection of two lines through the origin (i.e. two $1$-dimensional subspaces) is not itself a line through the origin (or the point $\{(0,0)\}$, or the entire plane) and is therefore not a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. Understand?